# PHP: Why isset is not working

Tags: php, html

I am newbie to PHP. It's very basic question.
Two Scenarios:

1.By Default on loading, June should be displayed.
2.If user click the submit button, Jan should be displayed.

simple.php ( PHP + HTML ) 
PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   echo "Jan";
else
echo "June";
```

HTML:

```
 <form method="post" action="simple.php" target='_self'>
        <input type='submit' id ="submit" value='Submit' name="submit"/>
 </form>
```

Now, When you click on submit button,its show June.
Please suggest me where I am going wrong. Please advice me.

Comment: Not sure if it's a copy+pasta error, but if you're not using bracers to separate the if/else statements, in your case, June will always display since it's not intended properly.

Comment: @Andrew bracers is not necessary

Comment: @FastSnail I didn't say they were necessary, I only said that without bracers indentation matters.

Comment: @Andrew Indentation does not matter to the comiler

Comment: Yep, you guys are absolutely right. Too much Python lately -.-

Comment: Hi! Is june showing or is it Jan? because in your question you are saying that it is June that is aways showing, but in the comments you are saying it's Jan, which one is it?

Comment: As because your code works, show please content of entire simple.php file.

Comment: @Epodax .First time ->June ,After clicked->Jan. On refresh->Jan, which should show june, but it is showing the jan.

Comment: @user007 Please read the comment of Megan Fox.

Comment: @user007 Did you check the other comments / Megan Fox's answer? if you submit and hit `F5` the form will be resubmitted.

Comment: @Andrew copy+pasta... lol!

Answer (score 2):

The code seems to be working on my PC. Did you surround the PHP code with the `<?php` and `?>` tags?

[image]

This is the code I used (simple.php):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
       echo "Jan";
    else
        echo "June";
?>

<form method="post" action="simple.php" target='_self'>
    <input type='submit' id ="submit" value='Submit' name="submit"/>
</form>
```

(By the way, you should remove the space in after the `id` tag in the HTML code)

Comment: Working fine in my PC as well . @michiel Without PHP tag how come june is printed

Comment: Code is right. First time loading it is showing the "June", but once you submit the button it shows "jan" and after that you try to refresh the page it still show the Jan only.

Comment: First time it should show June , Try refreshing properly . Ctrl + f5 then select the address bar and press enter and then check .

Comment: You shouldn't refresh the page to see the original result. It will resubmit the form. If you want to see the original result you need to do as @MeganFox said.

Comment: @MeganFox Okay.I will do as per suggestion and try it.

Comment: `To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.`
Are you getting this message when refreshing second time , though am unaware which browser u are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check with:

```
if (!empty($_POST))
```

OR

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Comment: When you refresh the page, it should shown the June, it is showing the Jan only.

Answer (score 0):

I think after you click the submit button once , you are pressing only f5 which submits the form again rather than refreshing the page .

Just Select the address bar and press enter and then check each time .

Comment: First time it shows June. Once You click it shows the Jan. After press F5 or Ctrl+F5  still it is showing the Jan. Is it working properly on your side.?

Comment: Just Select the address bar and press enter and then check each time . I told u in the answer

Answer (score 0):

`F5` may give you the same page even if the content is changed, because it may load the page from cache.

`Ctrl+F5` will cause the browser to throw out the cache and request a new from the server, the server may ignore the no-cache header and serve a server side cached page. Thus even Ctrl+F5 may return an old version of the page if the server ignores the no-cache header.
The request header contains some POST data. No matter what you do, when you reload the page, the rquest would be sent again.

The simple solution is to redirect to a new (if not the same) page. This pattern is very common in web applications, and is called Post/Redirect/Get. It's typical for all forms to do a POST, then if successful, you should do a redirect.

Please read this for more info 
[GET/POST/REDIRECT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)